# Crazy IE7 Horiztonal Scrollbar

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7, position

I'm using HTML5 boilerplate and have a **header** tag going the full width across the top of the page, with position:fixed. It works properly everywhere except IE7 (of course). In IE7 it creates a horizontal scrollbar that looks to have about the same width as the main content area...

Removing position:fixed from the **header** will remove the scrollbar and fix the issue, but I want to keep that position:fixed to have the whole **header** area overlap the main content as users scroll...

Anyone willing to take a look:  http://www.capitaldesign.ca/sanction3/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you try with overflow-x: hidden to the container div? it should make the scroll bars to not appear

Answer (score 0):

I can see you are using display: block on the header element.

Try removing this or making it a display: inline-block.